# how to set Epson L100 on ubuntu 12.04.

Tags: printing, epson

I can`t find drivers for this printer. I searching on http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule, but nothing. Maybe other series drivers can work with it?

Comment: Drivers for L100, L101, L200 and L201 are already avaiable at the epson website. Here is the link for L100 http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=PL&CN2=&DSCMI=24156&DSCCHK=95e99b2956fbf8c93b44cbd7a37f94836967528c

Answer (score 0):

Please search for "L200" and install that driver. According to the latest comments in the [Ubuntu Forums thread on that topic](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1671378) this driver should work.

Comment: I did it. I use drivers for epsonN11 from official download site. First printer settings (register ink id) I did through Virtualbox.

Comment: I don't understand, is your issue fixed now?

Comment: Yes. I fixed this issue according suggestion above. Thank you. P.S: sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Drivers for L100, L101, L200 and L201 are already avaiable at the epson website. Here is the link for L100 http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=PL&CN2=&DSCMI=24156&DSCCHK=95e99b2956fbf8c93b44cbd7a37f94836967528c

Just disconnect the printer, install the deb package, connect the printer back again, add printer in settings >> printers and choose the driver for L100
Alternatively you can do it through CUPS server at

> localhost:631/